# Generate random numbers without collisions

Tags: bash, random

I want to generate different random numbers in bash . I used $RANDOM , but in my output some numbers are identical.

```
var1=$((1+$RANDOM%48))
var2=$((1+$RANDOM%48))
var3=$((1+$RANDOM%48))
var4=$((1+$RANDOM%48))
var5=$((1+$RANDOM%48))
var6=$((1+$RANDOM%48))
```

it gives me 6 numbers between 1 and 48 but i need 6 DIFFERENT numbers between 1 and 48, the fact is that im really new and i dont know even how to start.

Comment: it should work fine, $RANDOM is a function, not a variable.

Comment: yes but in some cases for example i get  1  1  5  8  16  37 and the numbers need to be differents

Comment: yes, they are random; collisions are expected.  If you want all different 6 numbers, they are not independently random any more.

Comment: so how i need to do to get 6 different random numbers?

Comment: If you want them to be different, then it's not random. You want a set of numbers in random order. As others have commented, `shuf` of some list is the easiest way to get what you want. But it's important to understand the difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want 6 different pseudo-random numbers between 1-48 this is one way to make it

```
$ seq 48 | shuf | head -6


18
10
17
3
11
6
```

or directly with `shuf` options (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46944164/1435869))

```
shuf -i 1-48 -n 6
```

another method would be rejection sampling.  With `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN{srand(); 
           do {a[int(1+rand()*48)]} while (length(a)<6); 
           for(k in a) print k}'

8
14
16
23
24
27
```

here rejection is implicit, adding the same number again won't increase the array size (essentially a hash map)

to assign result to variable is possible, but the structure begs for array use, for example

```
declare -a randarray
readarray randarray < <(seq 48 | shuf | head -6)
```

you can access the individual elements with the corresponding index (0-based)

```
echo ${randarray[3]}
```

In general if your number of samples are close to the range of the sample space, you will want shuffle (extreme case if you want N numbers from the range 1-N, what you're asking is a random permutation), or if the ratio is small, rejection sampling might be better, (extreme case you want one random variable). Rejection sampling is used mostly if you have other conditions to eliminate a sample.  However, direct use of `shuf` with options is very fast already and you may not need rejection sampling method at all for basic uses.

Comment: but how do I declare those numbers in variables

Answer (score 3):

`shuf -i 1-48 -n 6`

will give you 6 random numbers between 1 and 48. All will be different per default.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm will roll six random numbers and check each of them to make sure there haven't been any duplicates.

```
declare -a nums

let times=6

for i in $(eval echo {0..$times}); do
    let nums[$i]=0
    let dup=1
    while [ $dup -eq 1 ]; do
        let temp=$((1+$RANDOM%48))
        let dup=0

        for j in $(eval echo {0..${#nums[*]}}); do
            let cur=$((${nums[$j]}))
            if ! [ "$cur" -eq "$cur" ] 2> /dev/null; then
                break
            fi
            if [ "$cur" -eq "$(eval echo $temp)" ]; then
                let dup=1
            fi
        done
    done

    let nums[$(($j - 1))]=$temp
done

echo ${nums[@]:0}

exit 1
```